# Typescript support for polymer v3

Tags: typescript, polymer, typescript-typings, polymer-3.x

I am currently testing polymer 3 preview to see how to integrate it into our team workflow.

The recommended way to declare an element in v3 is:

```
import { PolymerElement } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
...
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  ...
}
```

See: https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-03-23-polymer-3-latest-preview.html

This works well with typescript for basic things, but it does not understand that the class **MyElement** extends **HTMLElement**. So if I try to use **this.dispatchEvent(...)** in my code, the compilation will fail.

I tried to set a **.d.ts** to try to teach typescript but I could not get it to work. All those were pretty much unsuccessful.

1) Direct typing:

```
class PolymerElement extends HTMLElement{}
```

2) Typing the module:

```
declare module "polymer-element" {
    export class PolymerElement extends HTMLElement {}
}
```

And a few more variations but it never seem to be picked out by the transpiler.
Any idas ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you had to declare the module as `"@polymer/polymer/polymer-element"` instead of just `"polymer-element"`, unless you added the typings directly to the path `@polymer/polymer` in your `node_modules`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you're supposed to import `polymer-element.js` rather import `polymer-element`. The `.js` extension might interrupt adding the typings.

Comment: You put me in the right direction. What I had to do was 1) have the file be `@polymer/index.d.ts` 2) have the module declared as `@polymer/polymer/polymer-element` but 3) import `polymer-element`, not the `.js` file. @amit-b feel free to post an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you had to declare the module as `"@polymer/polymer/polymer-element"` instead of just `"polymer-element"`, unless you added the typings directly to the path `@polymer/polymer` in your `node_modules`.

Also, I'm not sure you're supposed to import `polymer-element.js` rather import `polymer-element`. The `.js` extension might interrupt adding the typings.

Answer (score 7):

As of version 3.0.5, TypeScript declarations are included in the [`@polymer/polymer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polymer/polymer) NPM package itself, and for all of the `iron-`, `paper-` etc. elements as of version 3.0.0.

```js
import {PolymerElement, html} from '@polymer/polymer';

class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`<p>Hello [[who]]</p>`;
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      who: String,
    };
  }
  who = 'World';
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

You can also uses the [`@polymer/decorators`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polymer/decorators) package to get better type safety and a more convenient syntax:

```js
import {PolymerElement, html} from '@polymer/polymer';
import {customElement, property} from '@polymer/decorators';

@customElement('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`<p>Hello [[who]]</p>`;
  }
  @property({type: String})
  who = 'World';
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to fetch the typings for polymer elements (i.e. paper-input) as well? I can see that each element has a typings.d.ts file present in its repo, but they aren't included when fetched with NPM. I thought about using the gen-typescript script, but that feels like a hack to include TypeScript in a project.

Comment: Typings for the 3.0 elements are not quite ready, but work is in progress. They'll be distributed either with the final version 3.0 releases, or shortly thereafter, sometimes in the next few weeks.

Comment: TypeScript typings for all of the 3.0 Polymer elements were published to NPM this week ([example](https://unpkg.com/@polymer/paper-button@3.0.1/paper-button.d.ts)).

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the heads up! I'll have another go at it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the v3 does not support TypeScript typings yet.

You can see a commit in the [v3.x branch](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/tree/3.x) titled [Delete typings for now.](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/commit/03d859822fc3a4146bb374cd1e4c2435e1f18fa5).

Solutions:

1.Just say to TypeScript to don't care yet:

```
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  fn(){
     (this as any).dispatchEvent(...) 
  }
}
```

2.Your element can declare to extends direclty from `HTMLElement`:

```
class MyElement extends PolymerElement, HTMLElement {
    fn() {
        this.dispatchEvent(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if they don't have official typings it should be possible to write custom ones to allow typescript to work.

Comment: you are kind of right, I propose a second solution, that involves adding an extra type in all you classes.

Comment: Sadly the second solution fails with `Classes can only extend a single class.`